# Idiomatic way of returning nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, return, null, idioms

Is it idiomatic in Ruby to not explicitly return `nil`? Let's say something like this:

```
def find_something data
    if data.has_what_we_need?
        a = data.something
        if a.has_what_we_want?
            a.the_stuff[42]
        end
    end
end
```

As opposed to something (arguably noisier) like this:

```
def find_something data
    if data.has_what_we_need?
        a = data.something
        if a.has_what_we_want?
            a.the_stuff[42]
        else
            nil
        end
    else
        nil
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to create methods that bail out early if conditions aren't met, flattening the code in terms of indentation:

```
def find_something data
  return unless data.has_what_we_need?

  a = data.something

  return unless a.has_what_we_want?

  a.the_stuff[42]
end
```

This has two well defined exit points, as `return` should show up as a fairly obvious thing when reading it. A `return` with no argument will return `nil` to the caller.

If you don't care about `nil` vs. `false` you can condense this even more:

```
def find_something data
  return unless data.has_what_we_need?

  a = data.something

  a.has_what_we_want? and a.the_stuff[42]
end
```

Comment: I like the postfix conditional for flow-control - as well as reducing indentation level, if it used mainly for flow control (as opposed for logic like `e = 3 if a.b?`), then it is quick to spot flow points when reading code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of a specific idiom pertaining to this, but this might be preferable:

```
def find_something data
    if data.has_what_we_need?
        a = data.something
        if a.has_what_we_want?
            return a.the_stuff[42]
        end
    end

    nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to avoid using `return` (and all the other flow breaking statements) in Ruby. Every time I see a `return` I think it could've been done better.

Comment: The funny thing is I agree. I would almost never do this in Java, but it seems fairly idiomatic in Ruby. I've adjusted accordingly in my own code, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: @detunized: Implied results that pop out from 3 lines back in the code  don't seem much better though. Sometimes it's better to make one thing explicit and readable over and above another. Code philosophies taken as absolutes can lead to some pretty awful code (some of the worst code I've seen recently has been due to promoting DRY above all other considerations).

Comment: Sounds like @Neil agrees with Obi-Wan: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgpytjlW5wU

Answer (score 2):

If by idiomatic you mean does ruby by default return nil from a method then no.

Ruby methods by default return the value of the last statement executed. If your last statement resolves to nil then your method will return a nil.

I'm assuming from your example that you want a method to return a value if found but nil if not found. Something like this might work:

```
def find_something (i)
    a = ['boris', 'natasha', 'moose' ,'squirrel']
    a[i]
end


irb(main):020:0> find_something 4
=> nil
irb(main):021:0> find_something 2
=> "moose"`
```

The result from the index into array a is the return value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By default methods in Ruby are empty, and an empty method returns, by default, nil.  You need to actually write something in the method to change this.  I should add that methods return the last line evaluated.